# Expaning scale effect of images behind themselves using CSS transitions

Tags: css, image, css-transitions, behind

I am creating an illustration portfolio site and using CSS transitions to scale boxes larger to show detailed thumbnails of work.

But I am struggling because when I hover over the thumbnails they always seem to be behind one another like so: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mmorrell2014/LdN5B/1/)

I need them to go in front and so the user can see detail of the images.

I have all the structure there, I just cant tell what I am doing wrong to make them go behind themselves.

Any help would really be appreciated.

This is the code for the scaling effect!

```
scale {
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
```

}

```
.scaleMe:hover {
transform: scale(1.2);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2);
-o-transform: scale(1.2);
-moz-transform: scale(1.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
-o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.scaleMe:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Giving a higher [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) will push it over lower z-index elements. The default is 0. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdN5B/3/)

Comment: To add to this, give your regular pics a z-index of, say, 1.  Give everything that you want to be on top of that something higher than 1.